# Github Api (PyGithub) delete/undo last commit to branch

Tags: python, github-api, pygithub

## Background

I am using a fork of the upstream repository where I created my own branch. I can commit to this branch and then create a pull request to the upstream. Committing again to the fork will naturally update the PR as well. This all works.

The issue is I want to add the ability to undo/delete a commit in the fork's branch using the github api, currently I am using the PyGithub package in python to interface with the Github Api but am willing to just send a request to the api directly if it isn't supported in PyGithub.

## Code/Attempts

```
git = Github(base_url="...", login_or_token="...") # create github connection
repo = git.get_user().get_repo("...") # will get fork

ref = repo.get_git_ref("heads/"+branch_name) # get ref to branch

## Attempt 1
# ref.delete() # will delete entire branch

## Attempt 2
# last_commit = repo.get_branch(branch_name).commit.sha # get commit at head of branch
# ref = repo.get_git_ref(last_commit) # does not accept sha even though documentation says it should https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/refs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-reference
# ref.delete() # maybe it will delete just the commit?

## Attempt 3
# last_commit = repo.get_branch(branch_name).commit.sha # get commit at head of branch
# ... unsure how to edit ref to remove commit before making an update/edit happen
# ref.edit(sha=last_commit)
```

Normally if I was doing things locally I would just use git reset or git rebase to solve the problem but after skimming the documentation couldn't find a similar api command for the remote repo. Any ideas?